# How to handle HeaderValueException in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish

We have REST endpoints with Jersey + Spring and when we do a request to our endpoint with a malformed header value. For example `Accept: application/json/foobar` a Exception with HeaderValueException is thrown.

This in return generate a HTML page with a bad request and leaks information about the server we are running.

Looking in jersey code it seems that HeaderValueException is handled different and I cannot seem to make the ExceptionMapper to work with this. (https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.7/source-code/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerRuntime.java under comment // internal mapping)

We want to return a custom JSON in this particular case.

How do we go about making sure that all exceptions, even HeaderValueException is under our control?

Note: When doing this our endoint is not been called yet..

Comment: '*I cannot seem to make the ExceptionMapper to work with this.'* Why is that? What have you tried to make this approach work?